# Encrypt data prior to Serialization

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am trying to encrypt data that a serializable (xml) class contains. Here is a simple example:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("FooClass")] 
public class FooClass
{
    private string _personalData;

    public PersonalData
    {
        set { _personalData = value;}
        get { return _personalData; }
    }
}
```

Assume there are ready to be used tho methods: `Encrypt` & `Decrypt`. Is there a way to use them somehow during the serialization in order to encrypt `PersonalData` in the serialized output?

Comment: For whom should it be encrypted?  Give us some detail from the user's perspective about how the data should be encrypted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Mark PersonalData as nonserialized, then add a new property to return and accept the serialized data (note that the XmlAttribute is optional):

```
[XmlRootAttribute("FooClass")] 
public class FooClass
{
    private string _personalData;

    [NonSerialized()]
    public string PersonalData
    {
        set { _personalData = value;}
        get { return _personalData; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("PersonalData")]
    public string PersonalDataEncrypted
    {
        set { _personalData = DecryptData(value);}
        get { return EncryptData(_personalData); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy enought. Actually I was looking for an attribute that will guide serializer to use a specific encryption/decryption method

Comment: @odyodyodys: I haven't seen anything like this, probably because of the large number of parameters that would need to be specified in order to implement a symmetric algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  You can use OnSerializingAttribute, OnDeserializingAttribute, and XmlIgnore attributes:

```
private string _encryptedPersonalData;
private string _personalData;                    

[XmlIgnore]
public PersonalData
{                
    set { _personalData = value;}                
    get { return _personalData; }            
}

public string EncryptedPersonalData
{
    get { return _encryptedPersonalData; }
    set { _encryptedPersonalData = value; }
}

[OnDeserializingAttribute()]
internal void DecryptPersonalData(StreamingContext context)
{ 
    // Decrypt data here    
}


[OnSerializingAttribute()]
internal void EncryptPersonalData(StreamingContext context)
{ 
    // Encrypt data here    
}
```

Or something similar to this.  These methods will be called before serialization occurs.
More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty01x675(v=VS.80).aspx